# what are the essential things needed to become a android app developer?

Tags: android

i want to know everything which is used to develop a android app. By the way i'm good in C and C++. If any other programming language is needed to write android apps then please tell me. it would be great if anyone can suggest me some good books for beginner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start programming (specifically for android devices)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743494/how-to-start-programming-specifically-for-android-devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALthough this question is not much relevant but here are my opinions about the learning steps

1. Learn Java
2. Learn Object Oriented Concepts ( I think learning a OOL doesn't always mean learning OOP well)
3. Learn android

There are plenty of resources,,,,

to learn java my favourite link is [sun java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Start with the basics

For android [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) provides the best resources to start

Comment: but i thought that there is no need of learning OOP in android dev. Am i right or wrong?

Comment: @AmitSharma.. to create the basic program you don't need much knowledge about oop.. but to be a good programmer you must

Comment: it means i have to learn OOP also..... by the way thanx, u helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a good understanding of Java first. Learn the fundamentals then start learning the Android specifics. The Androids docs are a good place to start:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html